# all span of same class should have equal width and remain on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, width

i am not so good in css, so need your help.
i tried too much with `display: block;` `display: inline;` but can't understand  how to fix this desgin

```
.mainmenu{
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px; 
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;  
    display: block;
    padding:1px;
    border:1px solid #021a40;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color:black;
}
.mainmenu:hover{
    display: block;
    padding:2px;
    border:1px solid #021a40;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:highlight;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/FKLfQ/6/

Comment: don't repeat `ID`. you are repeating it `#mainmenu` on span tag

Comment: "but can't understand how to fix this design" what design..? how do we know what is the expected design unless you explain it, or provide an image or something..  :s

Comment: @TJ i have already provide the fiddle link

Comment: Used to this http://fiddle.jshell.net/FKLfQ/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#navigation {
    display:table;
}
span {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/FKLfQ/18/)

This takes up the width of the largest span to be the width of all the others, which is dynamic when the contents are changed.

Comment: The width seems to be constant on hover. Perhaps what you mean is the position of the spans? It is due to the padding in :hover. Check my updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Set your CSS to this:

```
.mainmenu{
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;  /* rounds corners for firefox */
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;  /* rounds corners for other browsers */
    display: block;
    padding:1px;
    border:1px solid #021a40;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color:black;
    width:250px;  /* ADD THIS */
    display:block;/* ADD THIS */
}
```

And then specify the `width` based on your preferences.

Also in your fiddle all `span` elements have the same id. Id must be unique

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/FKLfQ/15/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the `width` property, so the span could be equal; and second you have `comments` in the wrong manner. In the CSS comment it should be like this:

```
/* Comments should appear like it */
```

Check the **[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/FKLfQ/11/)**.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `//` is not a valid comment in CSS, comments should be inside `/* */`. So the following rules are not being applied. Then you just have to apply `display:inline-block` and a common width.

```
.mainmenu{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;  /* Rounds corners for Firefox */
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;  /* Rounds corners for other browsers */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #021a40;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color: black;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/FKLfQ/8/)

Answer (score 0):

For navigation you could use a list instead of span's

html

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li class="your-class"><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
      <li class="your-class"><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
      <li class="your-class"><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
      <li class="your-class"><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
.your-class{
   display: inline-block; // In 1 line
   width:250px; // Same width
}
```

Also:
You can only use an ID once, it's called identifier for something.
Classes are for reusing.

Answer (score 0):

Test this code:

```
.mainmenu{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;  // Rounds corners for Firefox
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;  // Rounds corners for other browsers
    display: block;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #021a40;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.mainmenu:hover{
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #021a40;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: highlight;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```